# Cascading foreign key DELETE with tables that have RESTRICT constraints

Tags: mysql, innodb, foreign-key

I have a database that stores recipes for multiple organizations. So every table has an org_id pointing to the `orgs` table to allow each organization to have their own set of recipes and ingredients.

Recipes come from 3 tables: `recipes` holds the name, creation date, etc. `recipe_ingredients` is a list of the ingredients and how much of each. `raw_materials` is the raw ingredient name, type, color, etc.

Since a raw material can be used in many recipes, `recipe_ingredients` has `ON DELETE RESTIRCT` on the raw_material_id.

Since `recipe_ingredients` only apply to a single recipe, it also has `ON DELETE CASCADE` on the recipe_id.

This works as I expect--I can't delete a raw material that is used in any recipe, and deleting a recipe deletes all of its ingredients. Groovy.

Now what I'd like is to be able to delete an entire organization from the `orgs` table and have it cascade to everything associated with it, so all three tables have `ON DELETE CASCADE` for their `org_id` key, but it appears that the cascade hits the `raw_materials` table first and fails its `RESTRICT` foreign key constraint.

This makes sense, but is there a way around it? I've read a little about triggers, but I don't understand yet how I'd use them to get this to happen.

[image: Relation diagram]

Edit:

Ended up going with the following trigger on the orgs table:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `orgs_before_delete` BEFORE DELETE ON `orgs`
 FOR EACH ROW DELETE FROM recipes
WHERE recipes.org_id=OLD.indx
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using triggers would be a bit messy

You should do the cascade delete manually

Perhaps something like this

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT indx INTO @indx_to_cascade FROM orgs WHERE ...;
DELETE FROM recipes            WHERE org_id = @indx_to_cascade ;
DELETE FROM recipe_ingredients WHERE org_id = @indx_to_cascade ;
DELETE FROM raw_materials      WHERE org_id = @indx_to_cascade ;
DELETE FROM orgs               WHERE indx   = @indx_to_cascade ;
ROLLBACK;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

If this happens quickly, then switch to `COMMIT` rather than `ROLLBACK`

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;
START TRANSACTION;
SELECT indx INTO @indx_to_cascade FROM orgs WHERE ...;
DELETE FROM recipes            WHERE org_id = @indx_to_cascade ;
DELETE FROM recipe_ingredients WHERE org_id = @indx_to_cascade ;
DELETE FROM raw_materials      WHERE org_id = @indx_to_cascade ;
DELETE FROM orgs               WHERE indx   = @indx_to_cascade ;
COMMIT;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```

Comment: Thank you for this. It wasn't exactly the solution I needed, but it got me there so I'm accepting it. What worked was setting a BEFORE DELETE trigger on orgs to delete from the recipes table first, which cascaded through recipe_ingredients, freeing up raw_materials to be deleted. I'll edit the solution into my question.